using runuser on a python script from ansible
I have a python script doing specific checks to a SAP HANA database. When I execute the script from the OS, everything works fine. But when I execute it from Ansible, the script hangs when it tries to execute a "runuser" command (because I need to switch from root to sidadm to execute some commands).
On Ansible, the script is called like this:
- name: Run SAPStopStart.py script
  shell: |- 
    python /opt/osit/sap/bin/SAPStopStart.py -a Check -s "all" --hrep "yes" --hsql "yes"
  become: true
  become_user: root
  register: sap_stop_start_out
  ignore_errors: yes
  timeout: 120

The "problematic" code on the python script is the following:
    # check if replication is enabled/configured
    cmd2send = "runuser -l " + str(hana_sidadm) + " -c 'source ~/.profile && hdbnsutil -sr_state'"
    cmd_output, cmd_error, cmd_rc = cmd_execution(cmd2send)

The "cmd_execution" function simply executes the command on OS, like this:
def cmd_execution(cmd2execute):
    current_cmd = str(cmd2execute)
    p_cmd = subprocess.Popen(current_cmd, shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdOut_p_cmd, stdErr_p_cmd = p_cmd.communicate()
    eC_p_cmd = p_cmd.returncode
    p_cmd.stdout.close()
    stdOut_cmd = stdOut_p_cmd.decode("utf-8")
    stdErr_cmd = stdErr_p_cmd.decode("utf-8")

    return stdOut_cmd, stdErr_cmd, eC_p_cmd

I also noticed this works fine from Ansible when executed on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12.5 SP5, but the process hangs on OS (when it reaches the "runuser" part) on Linux SuSE Enterprise Server 15.4.
So, could this be "only" a specific configuration introduced after v12.5 SP5?
When executed from the OS, the python script works fine on any OS version.
Thanks
